# [Android]Update textview from another class running on asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview

my question is this, I have my main class, she command to run a AyncTask with a URL audio, at the end repreduce the next audio, my question is, I have the player in another class, as I do so the TextView which is updated every actualize the url of the song to play?
Here my code:

Activity main:
AsyncTask

```
public class Repoduce extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //mostrarNotificacion("Reproduciendo...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String url = strings[0];
        try {
            PlayAudioManager.playAudio(getApplicationContext(), url, Lista);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  //titulo.setText(guardaDatos.getArtista());
                                  titulo_cancion.setText(guardaDatos.getArtista());
                                  Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(guardaDatos.getCoverURL()).into(caratula);
                              }
                          }

            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

Here class with media player

```
 public static void playAudio(final Context context, final String url, String currentTrack) throws Exception {
    mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    listaReproduccion a = new listaReproduccion(context);
    //am = MusicPlayer.getAm();
    //am.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    codigos = a.getArray("Codigos");
    nombres = a.getArray("Nombres");
    artista = a.getArray("Artista");
    //guardaDatos.setArtista(nombres.get(cancion));
    setIsPlaying(true);

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(codigos.get(cancion)));
                //coverDeezer.caratulaArtista(artista.get(cancion));
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (cancion <= codigos.size()) {
                            try {
                                cancion++;
                                playAudio(context, "", "lista");
                                Log.i("CONTADOR2", String.valueOf(cancion));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

I have textview in activityclass, how to update this from class player  automatically?

Comment: Pass TextView to `playAudio ` method as argument

Comment: not work... :(   W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some solutions below if you want update textview in another activity :

1 - Create interface listener catch event change audio to update TextView.

2 - Use Broadcast receiver.

3 - Use Handler Message.

Answer (score 0):

Make the AsyncTask inside (inner class) of your Acitivity and call .setTex() inside the onPostExecute() method